# Can something in my Nginx config imply why my backend is not sending the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in POST request?

Tags: nginx, docker

*Edit 1: The error seem to be only with `POST` requests

I have a frontend website on `localhost`.
There is a registration page on `localhost/register`

The website calls a backend function to register a user at `localhost:8080/api/register`

I use Axios to POST the username and password.
The browser sends two requests: OPTIONS pre-flight request, and then the POST request.

The user is created successfully, however the browser throws an error for the POST request:

```
Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
```

And indeed it's missing in the response to the POST.
Assuming my backend cors file is configured properly, could the issue be from the combination of my Docker + Nginx setup that blocks it or proxy the headers to a wrong place?

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    index index.php index.html;    
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {        
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    
}

  server {    
    listen       80;       
      location / {      
      proxy_pass      http://node:3000;
      
    }
  }
```

and this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
    mynetwork:
        driver: bridge

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "80:80"            
        volumes:            
            - ./php:/var/www/html 
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            
        depends_on:
            - php
            - node
        networks:
            - mynetwork
    
    php:        
        build:
            context: ./php
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        user: "1000:1000"
        volumes:
            - ./php:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - mynetwork

    node:
        build:
            context: ./react
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: next        
        volumes:
            - ./react:/var/www/html                
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"       

        networks:
            - mynetwork
```

**Edit 2:

The backend is Laravel and it has a CORS middleware that is supposed to take care of it. And in fact it does seem to be working because `GET` and `OPTIONS` request pass without error, only the `POST` request throws this error.

This is the CORS config file (`cors.php`) in Laravel:

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true
```

Comment: There is nothing in this configuration that would add the CORS header. You need to take care of it.

Comment: Thank you. You are right that nginx does not have anything, but the backend has a middlware that takes care of that, and in fact when I send `GET` and `OPTIONS` request it does send the correct headers. But with `POST` not.
As you said, in order to fix the `POST` request issue, I added the following to the PHP server block and it now works:
`if ( $request_method = POST ){
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
}`.
But why I don't need that for `GET` and `OPTIONS`? added the backend code

Comment: We can only guess what the thought process of the middleware developer has been when they have implemented it.

Comment: So for now I should keep my code inside the server block for `POST` requests? Does my new config seem OK to you, or I'm missing something that might cause issues? (It's working, but maybe I can make it better)

Comment: Yes, the `server` block is fine. However, the best practice is to reverse proxy a path to the backend URL instead of using another port for different backend access.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to change my current config to do it? I thought that's what I'm already doing by proxying to my backend at port 8080?

Comment: The term reverse proxy above was not accurate actually. You need to do a `location /api` block inside the `server` block with port 80, and then move the configuration for port 8000 under that section. That is, you should serve the backend via port 80 too, just with a different prefix.

Comment: I did something slightly different: I used sub-domain instead of `/api` route. The way I did it was to first add `api.mysite.local` to the `hosts` file and then added a server block that listens on port `80` and redirects requests to the server block that listens on port `8080` like so: `return 301 https://api.mysite.local$request_uri;` - is this also a good practice?

Comment: This really looks like an issue with Laravel rather than your nginx configuration. Have you sought help with it on [so]? You may wish to do so.